# Build a Depth Level Object from a Flat Array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, tree, reduce

I have a Flat Array of Objects which has parent and child Relationship's but it is not very straight forward.

Every Entry of an Object has FromEntityId (Parent) and ToEntityId (Child)
First I need to find parent or all the parents which are the object's FromEntityId that is not present in any of the other Oject's ToEntityId and the Children will be of that Parent Object's FromEntityId to the ToEntityId

Here below is the OriginalData

```
    OriginalData = [
    {
    "FromEntityId": 266,
    "ToEntityId": 348,
    "Status": "NULL"
    },
    {
    "FromEntityId": 266,
    "ToEntityId": 353,
    "Status": "NULL"
    },
    {
    "FromEntityId": 266,
    "ToEntityId": 365,
    "Status": "NULL"
    },
    {
    "FromEntityId": 359,
    "ToEntityId": 350,
    "Status": "NULL"
    },
    {
    "FromEntityId": 359,
    "ToEntityId": 354,
    "Status": "NULL"
    },
    {
    "FromEntityId": 359,
    "ToEntityId": 361,
    "Status": "NULL"
    },
    {
    "FromEntityId": 359,
    "ToEntityId": 364,
    "Status": "NULL"
    },
    {
    "FromEntityId": 359,
    "ToEntityId": 372,
    "Status": "NULL"
    },
    {
    "FromEntityId": 362,
    "ToEntityId": 357,
    "Status": "NULL"
    },
    {
    "FromEntityId": 365,
    "ToEntityId": 369,
    "Status": "NULL"
    },
    {
    "FromEntityId": 369,
    "ToEntityId": 670,
    "Status": "NULL"
    },
    {
    "FromEntityId": 266,
    "ToEntityId": 349,
    "Status": "NULL"
    },
    {
    "FromEntityId": 266,
    "ToEntityId": 359,
    "Status": "NULL"
    },
    {
    "FromEntityId": 350,
    "ToEntityId": 351,
    "Status": "NULL"
    },
    {
    "FromEntityId": 359,
    "ToEntityId": 352,
    "Status": "NULL"
    },
    {
    "FromEntityId": 359,
    "ToEntityId": 355,
    "Status": "NULL"
    },
    {
    "FromEntityId": 359,
    "ToEntityId": 362,
    "Status": "NULL"
    },
    {
    "FromEntityId": 359,
    "ToEntityId": 365,
    "Status": "NULL"
    },
    {
    "FromEntityId": 361,
    "ToEntityId": 358,
    "Status": "NULL"
    },
    {
    "FromEntityId": 273,
    "ToEntityId": 356,
    "Status": "NULL"
    },
    {
    "FromEntityId": 266,
    "ToEntityId": 385,
    "Status": "NULL"
    },
    {
    "FromEntityId": 266,
    "ToEntityId": 389,
    "Status": "NULL"
    },
    {
    "FromEntityId": 266,
    "ToEntityId": 388,
    "Status": "NULL"
    },
    {
    "FromEntityId": 266,
    "ToEntityId": 382,
    "Status": "NULL"
    },
    {
    "FromEntityId": 369,
    "ToEntityId": 380,
    "Status": "NULL"
    },
    {
    "FromEntityId": 273,
    "ToEntityId": 381,
    "Status": "NULL"
    },
    {
    "FromEntityId": 273,
    "ToEntityId": 672,
    "Status": "NULL"
    }
]
```

Here below is the FinalData

```
finalData = [
      {
        "FromEntityId": 266,
        "Status": "NULL",
        "depthLevel": 0,
        "children": [
          {
            "FromEntityId": 266,
            "ToEntityId": 348,
            "Status": "NULL",
            "depthLevel": 1
          },
          {
            "FromEntityId": 266,
            "ToEntityId": 353,
            "Status": "NULL",
            "depthLevel": 1
          },
          {
            "FromEntityId": 266,
            "ToEntityId": 365,
            "Status": "NULL",
            "depthLevel": 1,
            "children": [
              {
                "FromEntityId": 365,
                "ToEntityId": 369,
                "Status": "NULL",
                "depthLevel": 2,
                "children": [
                  {
                    "FromEntityId": 369,
                    "ToEntityId": 670,
                    "Status": "NULL",
                    "depthLevel": 3
                  },
                  {
                    "FromEntityId": 369,
                    "ToEntityId": 380,
                    "Status": "NULL",
                    "depthLevel": 3
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "FromEntityId": 266,
            "ToEntityId": 385,
            "Status": "NULL",
            "depthLevel": 1
          },
          {
            "FromEntityId": 266,
            "ToEntityId": 389,
            "Status": "NULL",
            "depthLevel": 1
          },
          {
            "FromEntityId": 266,
            "ToEntityId": 388,
            "Status": "NULL",
            "depthLevel": 1
          },
          {
            "FromEntityId": 266,
            "ToEntityId": 382,
            "Status": "NULL",
            "depthLevel": 1
          },
          {
            "FromEntityId": 266,
            "ToEntityId": 349,
            "Status": "NULL",
            "depthLevel": 1
          },
          {
            "FromEntityId": 266,
            "ToEntityId": 359,
            "Status": "NULL",
            "depthLevel": 1,
            "children": [
              {
                "FromEntityId": 359,
                "ToEntityId": 354,
                "Status": "NULL",
                "depthLevel": 2
              },
              {
                "FromEntityId": 359,
                "ToEntityId": 361,
                "Status": "NULL",
                "depthLevel": 2,
                "children": [
                  {
                    "FromEntityId": 361,
                    "ToEntityId": 358,
                    "Status": "NULL",
                    "depthLevel": 3
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "FromEntityId": 359,
                "ToEntityId": 364,
                "Status": "NULL",
                "depthLevel": 2
              },
              {
                "FromEntityId": 359,
                "ToEntityId": 372,
                "Status": "NULL",
                "depthLevel": 2
              },
              {
                "FromEntityId": 359,
                "ToEntityId": 352,
                "Status": "NULL",
                "depthLevel": 2
              },
              {
                "FromEntityId": 359,
                "ToEntityId": 355,
                "Status": "NULL",
                "depthLevel": 2
              },
              {
                "FromEntityId": 359,
                "ToEntityId": 362,
                "Status": "NULL",
                "depthLevel": 2,
                "children": [
                  {
                    "FromEntityId": 362,
                    "ToEntityId": 357,
                    "Status": "NULL",
                    "depthLevel": 3
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "FromEntityId": 359,
                "ToEntityId": 365,
                "Status": "NULL",
                "depthLevel": 2
              },
              {
                "FromEntityId": 359,
                "ToEntityId": 350,
                "Status": "NULL",
                "depthLevel": 2,
                "children": [
                  {
                    "FromEntityId": 350,
                    "ToEntityId": 351,
                    "Status": "NULL",
                    "depthLevel": 3
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "FromEntityId": 273,
        "Status": "NULL",
        "depthLevel": 0,
        "children": [
          {
            "FromEntityId": 273,
            "ToEntityId": 356,
            "Status": "NULL",
            "depthLevel": 1
          },
          {
            "FromEntityId": 273,
            "ToEntityId": 381,
            "Status": "NULL",
            "depthLevel": 1
          },
          {
            "FromEntityId": 273,
            "ToEntityId": 672,
            "Status": "NULL",
            "depthLevel": 1
          }
        ]
      }
    ];
```

I am trying to use reduce method of an Array in JavaScript, but still not able to achieve the Desirable output.

Answer (score 0):

you have more of a logical problem I suppose. Make an array with child parent relationship. f.e.

```
 var cparr = []; 
 cparr[ichild] = iparent;
```

Then if an object has no parrent it is an 0 depth object. List these objects in a new final data object array. All children of the first objects will be pushed as cildren in the parent object which you will do in a second loop over the whole data.

you will get the adress where to put the children from the first parent children array.

I am sorry but you have to do the work to do this yourself.

Kind Regards

Kilian

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am not really convinced about the desired solutions, it might take me an Year to come up with the solution for sure,...